# receiving no data from [/ardrone/navdata_gps] topic

Tags: ros, gps, ardrone2.0, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with the gps-waypoint branch of the ardrone driver. I follow the steps of the
website but in the end I always get the same message (''topic [/ardrone/navdata_gps] does not appear to be published yet'') when I try to see what is being published on this topic. I already checked that the parameter "_enable_navdata_gps" is set to true.

I have no idea what the problem is.
The firmware of the GPS module is the last one and I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 .

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218846/receiving-no-data-from-%5B/ardrone/navdata_gps%5D-topic/) by [JCUAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/24345/jcuav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-10-08**:
How do you enable `navdata_gps`? Could you please specify the exact command you use to execute the driver?

**Comment by [JCUAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/24345/jcuav/) on 2015-10-09**:
$ rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver _enable_navdata_gps:=True

I have already found the solution but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After using another computer I realized it was some kind of path problem. The first time I used the binary installation for the driver but the GPS branch is intalled from source. Therefore when we ran the package, the path /opt/ros/indigo/share/ardrone_autonomy was followed instead of using the files from the catkin workspace.

What I did is to unistall the ardrone_autonomy driver with the command "$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy".
At this point (after running the driver again), I was able to see "/ardrone/navdata_gps" between the list of topics but when we typed "rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata_gps" we got the message "Cannot load message class for [/ardrone/navdata_gps]. Are your messages built?". The solution to this is to clean the workspace (catkin_make clean),then build it (catkin_make) and finally source the path (source devel/setup.bash).

Hopefully this is helpful.

---

Originally posted by [JCUAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/24345/jcuav/) with karma: 41 on 2015-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on 2017-06-17**:
Hi @JCUAV,
I am still struggling with this. I am on ROS Kinetic running on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the ardrone autonomy like "$apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy" and then  I sourced the bash file in /opt/ros/kinetic. When I launch the autonomy node, I dont see the GPS topic. Help Plz

**Comment by [Maureen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30848/maureen/) on 2017-07-03**:
so useful!!!